# How can I browserify BokehJS

Tags: javascript, browserify, bokeh

When I import `bokehjs`

```
require('bokehjs');
```

and then run a browserify Grunt task on it, I get

```
Running "browserify:main" (browserify) task
>> Error: Cannot find module 'core/bokeh_events' from '/home/jasper/Projects/meadows/node_modules/bokehjs/build/js/tree'
```

Answer (score 1):

bokehjs often uses absolute module references, so you have to set `paths` option to contain `bokehjs/build/js/tree` (absolute or relative to `basedir`; see browserify's documentation for details).